# Can I tell if there's a Wifi Repeater on my network?

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

If I have clients connecting to my network (through a captive portal) over Wifi, is it technically possible for me to determine if there is a Wifi Repeater connected somewhere in the mix?

If so, what is some software that can answer this question for my network?

Comment: The only way to tell is if you were able to identify a device in the client list on your router. A WiFi repeater will have an IP and MAC address, same as any other device.

Comment: Every repeater on the network will effect and the quality of the network it creates will be lower then the original network

Comment: By "WiFi repeater", do you mean a device that connects to your WiFi as a client and then does MAC address translation to make devices connected to it by WiFi appear to be clients of one of your access points?

Comment: None of these seem to answer the OP. Wifi Repeaters (an official spec) don't add any MACs or IPs to the network AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

A repeater requires the SSID and Password to the router that it's connecting to in order to A) connect to the WiFi network, and B) allow other devices to connect to the network.  To remove any WiFi Repeaters from your network, all you have to do is change 1 or both the SSID and Password.

Now, as for finding the hidden WiFi Repeater, you will need a sniffer.  This device will send a specific sequence of packets through your network and trace them wirelessly.  From there, you basically play the childrens game of Hot / Cold.  The stronger the signal, the closer you are to the Repeater.